# PyMongo query not returning results although the same query returns results in mongoDB shell

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
import pymongo
uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
db = client.TeamCity
students = db.students.find({})
for student in students:
    print (student)
```

---

Python Result:

### Blank

MongoDB: Results

```
db.students.find({})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5788483d0e5b9ea516d4b66c"), "name" : "Jose", "mark" : 99 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57884cb3f7edc1fd01c3511e"), "name" : "Jordan", "mark" : 100
}
```

---

```
import pymongo
uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
db = client.TeamCity
students = db.students.find({})
print (students.count())
```

---

Python Result:

### 0

mongoDB Results

```
db.students.find({}).count()

2
```

---

What am I missing?

For

```
import pymongo
uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
db = client.TeamCity
students = db.students.find({})
print (students)
```

Python Result :

So I think it is able to connect to the db successfully but not returning results

Comment: Can you show the name of your database in mongoDB shell, i.e. the output of the command 'db'

Comment: > show dbs
Teamcity  0.000GB
local     0.000GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your pymongo code like so, i.e. changing `TeamCity` to `Teamcity`

Print all students:

```
import pymongo
uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
db = client.Teamcity
students = db.students.find({})
for student in students:
    print (student)
```

Count all students:

```
import pymongo
uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
db = client.Teamcity
students = db.students.find({})
print (students.count())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured it when you asked to show the name of my .database

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered long ago, but I ran into the same kind of problem today and it happened to have a different reason, so I'm adding an answer here.

Code working on shell:

```
> db.customers.find({"cust_id": 2345}, {"pending_questions": 1,  _id: 0})
{ "pending_questions" : [ 1, 5, 47, 89 ] }
```

Code not working in PyMongo (cust_id set through a web form):

```
db.customers.find({"cust_id": cust_id}, {"pending_questions": 1,  "_id": 0})
```

It turned out that the numbers in the shell are being interpreted as ints, whereas the numbers used in Python code are being interpreted by PyMongo as floats, and hence return no matches. This proves the point:

```
cust_id = int(request.args.get('cust_id'))
db.customers.find({"cust_id": cust_id}, {"pending_questions": 1,  "_id": 0})
```

which produces the result:
`[1.0, 5.0, 47.0, 89.0]`

The simple solution was to typecast everything to int in the python code. In conclusion, the data type inferred by the shell may be different from the data type inferred by PyMongo and this may be one reason that a find query that returns results on the shell doesn't return anything when run in PyMongo.